# Parent Child Document Mapping in ElasticSearch via AWS SQS Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-sqs, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

Does the AWS SQS River Plugin for elasticsearch support the _parent field during indexing?  If so, how? The documentation is not clear and I've tried both of the following:

```
{
"_id": "123",
"_parent":"parent_id"
"_index": "es_index_name",
"_type": "es_data_type",
"_data": { "key1": "value1" ...}
}
```

And

```
{
"_id": "123",
"_index": "es_index_name",
"_type": "es_data_type",
"_data": { "_parent":"parent_id", "key1": "value1" ...}
}
```

Both give a RoutingMissingException

Comment: Can you give your full index mapping, and exactly how you index the data?

Comment: There did not seem to be a way.  Ended up going the rabbitmq route, which has been working fine.  The message body json also more closely matches that of the elasticsearch api.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SQS river plugin for Elasticsearch does not support the `_parent`, neither does it support the new `join` datatype. The plugin was meant to have pretty basic functionality but unfortunately it's now **deprecated**. This is because rivers have been [deprecated since Elasticsearch 1.5](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers).

If you still wish to implement the `_parent` field and you're still using the plugin with an older version of ES, feel free to contact me. I wrote the plugin and I should be able to help you out.